# Express - Accessing Client's IP when Index.html is Requested

Tags: node.js, express

I am service static files to the client on request via:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I would like to access the IP address of the client on request of index.html (which is in the public folder). Is it possible to do this by customizing the `express.static` method? If so, how? If it is not, what is the best way to do this?

Edit: I need to do this as a fallback in case HTML5 Geolocation API is not allowed/supported by the client. The IP address is sent to 1 API from which longitude and latitude position are received. Afterwards, the longitude and latitude are sent to a second API to receive the data that is essential to the app I am building. This data will then be served to the client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only)

Comment: @jmargolisvt Definitely not a duplicate. I need to get the IP address of the client that is requesting the index.html file to make a request to a third-party API and serve that API's response data along with the index.html file. The IP address is needed for geolocation which is passed on to the API. This is a fallback in case the html5 geolocation API is not allowed by the client.

Comment: @Ignat If you are saying you want to inject the ip or the location on to the index.html page then you are not serving a static page at that point. You will need a template that has a placeholder for where that information will go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use req.ip to get the remote IP address:

```
req.ip
// => "127.0.0.1"
```

From the docs: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip

Just create a middleware that processes the request before the static route and call `next()` at the end.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.ip);
  next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the way to access the ip address. The problem is that how do you access it when you only have the `app.use(express.static('public'));`?